# How to get the actual size of an embedded SVG element, if it's auto-resizing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I set up an auto-resizing SVG that changes size based on the parent container while keeping the aspect ratio.

I want to center the SVG element in the parent container because the dimensions of the parent container doesn't necessary match the SVG's dimensions .

I created a fiddle to demonstrate what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/lazthewiz/cXx46/

#### HTML

```
<DIV>
<SVG id=svg viewBox="0 0 160 90" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin">
...
```

#### CSS

```
DIV {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;    
}

SVG {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The *width* and *height* values returned by jQuery or found in the DOM are useless in this case. They either return zero, or the parent container's dimensions (depending on what browser you use).

Is there a way to get the actual dimensions of the embedded SVG either with jQuery or plain JS?

Answer (score 3):

I actually found the solution which is far less involved (but a bit hacky) than doing aspect ratio calculations.

The trick was that I created an invisible line (no stroke) from the top left corner to the bottom right corner of the SVG canvas. 
Then I got the actual screen dimensions of the bounding box of that line.

So with an example:

#### HTML

```
<SVG viewBox="0 0 160 90" ...>
   ...
   <line x1=0 y1=0 x2=160 y2=90 id=dimline />
</SVG>
```

#### JS

```
var width=$("#dimline")[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
var height=$("#dimline")[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
```

And here's a fiddle that works on FF, Chrome and IE: http://jsfiddle.net/lazthewiz/cXx46/5/

(In IE it adds a couple of pixels of what would be expected but that's not a big deal for centering purposes).

Answer (score 1):

I reckon so. Haven't tested with anything other than Google Chrome (33.0.1750.154 m).
For your code/styles, I actually get the value of 200 and 112.5 (rather than 200x113)

```
var mImg = document.getElementById('svg');
var aspect = mImg.viewBox.baseVal.height / mImg.viewBox.baseVal.width;
var width = mImg.clientWidth;
var height = width * aspect;
var msg = '';
msg += 'width: ' + width;
msg += ', ';
msg += 'height: ' + height;
document.body.appendChild( document.createTextNode(msg) );
```

I suppose that this would fail if the image was tall, instead of wide - but I guess you could decide how to calculate the size correctly based on which dimension of the viewBox was larger - the width or the height.

Comment: Thanks. But, unfortunately, your code returns zeros in Firefox.

Comment: Bugger! Worked okay with IE9 and Opera - dont have FF to try with. You could always inspect the element in FF to see which properties it does have. (That's what I did in chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cross-browser method that works well when the Div width=height. There are a few differences between browser as shown below:

```
function fitSVGinDiv()
{

    var divWH=parseInt(divWHValue.value)
    svgDiv.style.width=divWH+"px"
    svgDiv.style.height=divWH+"px"

    var bb=mySVG.getBBox()
    var bbw=bb.width
    var bbh=bb.height

    //--use greater of bbw vs bbh--
    if(bbw>=bbh)
        var factor=bbw/divWH
    else
        var factor=bbh/divWH

    var vbWH=divWH*factor

    var vbX=(bbw-vbWH)/2
    var vbY=(bbh-vbWH)/2
    //---IE/CH---
    if(!isFF)
    {
        var ViewBox=mySVG.viewBox.baseVal
        ViewBox.x=vbX
        ViewBox.y=vbY
        ViewBox.width=vbWH
        ViewBox.height=vbWH
    }
    else
        mySVG.setAttribute("viewBox",vbX+" "+vbY+" "+vbW+" "+vbH)

    //--requred for FF/CH---
    if(!isIE)
    {
        mySVG.setAttribute("width","100%")
        mySVG.setAttribute("height","100%")
    }
    else
    {
        mySVG.removeAttribute("width")
        mySVG.removeAttribute("height")
    }
}
```